# Do integer right-angled tetrahedra exist?

Tags: geometry, diophantine-equations

Are there any tetrahedra, with integer side lengths (A,B,C,D,E,F) AND three right angle-triangle faces (ABD, BCE and CDF)?

[image]

In algebraic terms, this amounts to the question: are there three integers; A, B and C; which fulfil the set of pythagorean equations:

A^2 + B^2 = D^2

B^2 + C^2 = E^2

A^2 + C^2 = F^2

Comment: This is related to [the perfect cuboid problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCuboid.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such tetrahedra do exist. The associated rectangular prisms are known as [Euler bricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick).  The smallest Euler brick (by volume) is given by $A = 44$, $B = 117$, and $C = 240$.